# Zest 1.1.0 cannot integrate with ZK 6.5.2

Tags: spring, rest, maven, zk

I am using ZK framework version 6.5.2 for my application. And now I want to integrate RESTful to it by using Zest. The problem is, the latest version of Zest is 1.1.0, and it depends on zcommon-5.0.0. So this dependency (zcommon-5.0.0) is duplicated and I excluded it from my POM file, like this:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.zkoss.zest</groupId>
      <artifactId>zest</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.zkoss.common</groupId>
          <artifactId>zcommon</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.zkoss.common</groupId>
          <artifactId>zweb</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

As a result zest now depends on zcommon-6.5.2. When I start my app, an error occured:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.zkoss.xel.taglib.FunctionDefinition
    at org.zkoss.xel.taglib.Taglibs.getFunctionMapper(Taglibs.java:150)
    at org.zkoss.xel.taglib.Taglibs.getFunctionMapper(Taglibs.java:109)
    at org.zkoss.zest.sys.impl.ParserImpl.parse(ParserImpl.java:97)
    at org.zkoss.zest.sys.impl.ParserImpl.parse(ParserImpl.java:54)
    at org.zkoss.zest.sys.ZestManager.loadConfiguration(ZestManager.java:98)
    at org.zkoss.zest.sys.ZestManager.init(ZestManager.java:70)
    at org.zkoss.zest.sys.ZestFilter.init(ZestFilter.java:74)
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>zest</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.zkoss.zest.sys.ZestFilter</filter-class>
    <!-- specifies the class name of the ZEST manager to handle actions Default: org.zkoss.zest.sys.ZestManager -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>manager-class</param-name>
      <param-value>org.zkoss.zest.sys.ZestManager</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- specifies the class name of the parser used to parse the configuration file (WEB-INF/zest.xml). Default: org.zkoss.zest.sys.impl.ParserImpl -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>parser-class</param-name>
      <param-value>org.zkoss.zest.sys.impl.ParserImpl</param-value>
    </init-param>

  </filter>
```

And here is rest definition in zest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zest>

  <xel-method prefix="c" name="toMethodName"
            class="com.myapp.view.RestAction"
        signature="java.lang.String toMethodName(java.lang.String)"/>
    <action path="/rest" method="${c:toMethodName(request.method)}"
    class="com.myapp.view.RestAction">
        <result>/WEB-INF/index.zul</result>
    </action>
</zest>
```

I have compared the source code of these 2 files Taglibs.java in version 5.0.0 and 6.5.2 of zcommon and realized that they have so many differences. I think that the reason caused above problems (the initialization process has changed from 5.0.5 to 6.5.2). Could you please help me solve this problem so that I can integrate zest to my ZK application? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zest 1.1 is not compatible with ZK 6.5.2. You have to upgrade to Zest 2.0:

http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2/org/zkoss/zest/zest/2.0.0.FL.20130205/